# Converting a piecewise function to a linear equation as a constraint

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, linearization

The value of one of the variable of my model (alpha_1) is given by a piecewise function. Each element of the piecewise depends on the value of some other binary decision variables (X1, x2, x3).

I'd like to know how I can express this piecewise function as some linear equations within the constraints to make sure that the right value has been chosen. Please below find the piecewise function.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure $\alpha_{1}$ is a parameter? A parameter is pre-defined while the value of the variables depends on the problem-solving process.

Comment: You are right. what a stupid error. Alpha then counts as variable. So, if I use big-M to convert this piecewise function into some equations, then the whole model wold become non-linear. Right?

Comment: Please, modify your question to get the right advice.

Comment: I just edit the question. Sorry for getting you confused

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you sure the above picture adopts your below comment? `Basically, the right hand side of the second and third statements at the if statement was not correct. i.e., x1 +x2 =2 and x1+x2+x3=1.`. It seems the modified picture does not change!!

Comment: I guess the formula in the modified picture is correct (x1 +x2 =2 and x1+x2+x3=3).  I think it is possible to use big-M. I should use 6 equations, two for each line of the if statement. I wonder if it is possible to formulate it without using Big-M

Comment: If $x_1+x_2+x_3=3,$ then $x_1+x_2=2$ and $x_1=1.$ So the pictured formula does not make sense. Did you mean $\alpha_1=100$ when *only* $x_1$ is 1? If so, is there something in the model ensuring that $x_2=1 \implies x_1=1?$ If not, how is $\alpha_1$ defined if, say, $x_1=0=x_3$ and $x_2=1?$

Comment: @prubin basically, alpha1 represent a cost associated with x1 as a main factor and other variables as optional ones. So, alpha1 takes a positive value if x1 takes 1. The rest of the variables are optional. They can be zero or 1. If they would take 1, the value of alpha_1 would change

Answer (score 1):

For the if statements try this
$x_1-(x_2+x_3) \le w_1$
$x_2-x_3 \le w_2 $
$x_3 \le w_3 $
$ w_1 +w_2+w_3 =1$
where $w$ are binary.
$\alpha = 100w_1 +200w_2 + 300w_3 $

As question now stands I d modify answer as
$ x_1 +x_2+x_3 = w_1+2w_2+3w_3$
$ \sum_i w_i =1$
You may also need 
$\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i \le Mx_k$ for $k=\{1,2,...n-1\}$

Comment: As the $\alpha$ is a parameter one can easily restrict the values of the variables on it by using an if-then/else statement.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I made a mistake in the if statement. Basically, the right hand side of the second and third statements at the if statement was not correct. i.e., x1 +x2 =2 and x1+x2+x3=1. May I ask you how this affect on the formula you provided earlier?

Comment: @Sam please check the answer if it works.

Comment: Many thanks Sutanu. As far as I see, there might be one situation that these constraints could not handle. That is, the situation where x1 and x3 would take the value of 1. The last constraint you added(sum of xi<= Mx_k) is to take care of this issue?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Great, many thanks for your help ! Greatly appreciated